# Looking for PyQGIS equivalent of ArcPy "SearchCursor" class

Tags: pyqgis, cursor, search

How can I consult and use shapefile attributes without reflections on the map? Like a 'Search Cursor object' from ArcObjects. Also using a query expression to filter data.

Comment: QGIS developers might have no idea what those words mean so please elaborate on what you want in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe playing with the layer `getFeatures` iterator and the `QgsFeatureRequest` ?

```py
# load layer
fileName = f"{QgsApplication.pkgDataPath()}/resources/data/world_map.gpkg|layername=countries"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
options = QgsVectorLayer.LayerOptions(QgsProject.instance().transformContext())
options.forceReadOnly = True
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(
    fileInfo.absoluteFilePath(),
    "World Map",
    "ogr",
    options
)
# or just : lyr = iface.activeLayer()  # active layer in the layer tree

# request
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression("\"NAME\" LIKE 'A%'")
request.setSubsetOfAttributes([])
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)

# cursor
cursor = lyr.getFeatures(request)
for row in cursor:
    print(f"{row[0]}, {row[1]}, {row[2]}")
```